# Подсчитать кол-во записей в каждой категории

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Требуется на сайте произвести подсчет, сколько записей находится в каждой категории, а так же подсчитать общее кол-во всех записей.

Допустим, есть 10 записей и 5 категорий. Каждая из 10 записей, относится ко всем 5 категориям (category='1,2,3,4,5').

Изначально пользовался запросом:

```
SELECT c.id, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dle_post p WHERE p.category = c.id) as newscount FROM dle_category c;
```

Получал массив с id категорий и кол-вом записей(newscount) в них.

id  newscount

1   10

2   0

3   0

4   0

5   0

А общее кол-во всех записей я подсчитывал, складывая значения 'newscount' уже в цикле php.

Но так как у меня каждая запись относится к нескольким категориям, мой запрос работал не корректно, он учитывал только первый id в ячейке 'category'.

Ситуацию исправил запросом:

```
SELECT c.id, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dle_post p WHERE p.category REGEXP (concat('[[:<:]]',c.id,'[[:>:]]'))) as newscount FROM dle_category c;
```

Он обрабатывал уже все категории, которые имеются в ячейке 'category'.

id  newscount

1   5

2   5

3   5

4   5

5   5

Но проблема в том, что, я теперь не знаю, как узнать общее кол-во всех записей? Ведь уже простое складывание в цикле php значений находящихся в 'newscount' выдаст неверные результаты.

Вот собственно сам код с запросом и обработкой:

```
$count_news = $db->query("SELECT ct.id, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . PREFIX . "_post ps WHERE ps.category = ct.id) as newscount FROM " . PREFIX . "_category ct");

while ( $res_count = $db->get_row($count_news) ) {
    $count_cat .= "\r\n" . $res_count['id'] . "|" . $res_count['newscount'];
    $all_news = $all_news+$res_count['newscount'];
}       

$count_all =  "0|" . $main_news . $count_cat;
```

На выходе получаем:

0|10

1|10

2|0

...

5|0

Первая строчка с id=0, это общее кол-во всех записей.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно изучить `JOIN`, он во много раз быстрее, чем вложенные запросы. Тогда вместо одного монстра сделайте просто 2 относительно легких запроса:

```
SELECT
  count(p.post_id)
FROM
  dle_category c left join  dle_post p on c.id=p.category group by c.id;
```

Второй запрос (если у вас правильно расставлены ключи) будет вообще невесомый, нужно лишь посчитать кол-во ключей:

```
SELECT
  count(distinct p.post_id)
FROM
  dle_post p
```

Рабочий пример:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34d5f4/5

Comment: Ваш первый запрос выполняется за 1.2431 сек. Если в нём заменить count(p.post_id) на count(*), то уже за 0.1870 сек.

Мой выполняется за 0.1440 сек.

Я что-то не так делаю, раз нет роста производительности, а наоборот, ещё медленнее выполняется? 
Тест делал на таблице с 10тыс. записями.

Comment: Я не знаю, как устроены ваши таблицы. Возможно `explain` бы помог. К слову 0.14 сек на всего 10тыс записей - это очень медленно